# Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it

Tags: wcf

When i'm using `SessionMode = SessionMode.Required` in servicecontract then i get this error

> Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't
>   support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

anyone tell me a solution?

Answer (score 12):

This error message is seldom clear. Here the answer goes like this, basichttpbinding doesn't support session. So you have to use the below property if you want to use it. 
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]

This means, If you are trying to configure multiple bindings like basichttp, wshttp, net.tcp, WCF will automatically enable session for other than basichttp binding. so if you put SessionMode.Required instead of Allowed, then you are forced not to use basichttpbinding.

That said, solving this issue usually would require something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" transactionFlow="true" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
      .......
```

Answer (score 10):

As it's listed [here](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/wcf-sessions/), choose `wsHttpBinding` or `NetTcpBinding.WSHttpBinding` binding.

Comment: I used the solution but the problem didn't go away and then I found one more thing to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930403/basic-http-binding-isnt-configured-properly) so don't forget to add this <protocolMapping> to your config...